# Number of solutions to large Diopanthine equation

Tags: combinatorics, diophantine-equations

I'm looking for the *number of solutions* (not the actual solutions) to the Diophantine equation

$\sum_{i=1}^N a_i * i = M $ of the form {$a_1$,$a_2$,...$a_n$}

where all the $a_i$ are integers greater than or equal to $0$.

I'm especially interested in the **limit where integers M and N are very large** (N in the range of $10^{23}$ and M in the range of $10^7$ to $10^{21}$).  Ideally the solution would be in the form of Number_of_Solutions[N, M] =...   Since these solutions will be very large, possibly it would be simpler to define a related function, Log_Number_of_Solutions[N, M].

Answer (score 0):

(More a comment)

Look up partitions, in particular, restricted partitions.

A reasonable start:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_partitions